# Unable to access the property throughout the controller cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Collection\Collection;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public $checkDataMember = null;
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->checkDataMember = 'Checking Data Member';
    }

    public function home() {
      pj($this->checkDataMember); // Output: Checking Data Member
      $this->checkDataMember = 'Checked Data Member';
    }


    public function dashboard() {
     pj($this->checkDataMember); // Output: Checking Data Member
   }

}
```

In the `dashboard()`, it should o/p as **Checked Data Member**, but it isn't. What is the problem ? I am unable to change the property of the class. Can anyone tell me, where the problem is ?

Comment: Why do you think it should output "Checked" instead of "Checking" in the dashboard function?

Comment: "home" function is the main home/index page of my site. So, when home page will open, I guess it will change the data member variable from 'Checking' to 'Checked'. Then, when I will go to my dashboard page, the value in the variable should be changed as the data member has scope throughout the controller. Please, correct me if I am wrong. @GregSchmidt

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. Every request you make to your site, every page you load, is a completely new process. When you load the home page, the controller is created and initialized and `checkDataMember` is set by the `home` function. Then it's destroyed. You then load the dashboard page, the controller is created and initialized, and `checkDataMember` will be "Checking" again. To make data persist over multiple page loads, you need to save it somewhere, like a session.

Comment: If that's the case, then I have implemented using Session as well, but the problem is: 1. When I implement it locally, it works but when I deploy it in the server, it does not. Please, check the code here: [LINK](https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/reading-session-variables-auth-allowed-methods/7434) 2. As you can see that, I have removed the authorization on both the methods. But, when I does not remove the authorization, it works fine bcoz the session persists. But I need those methods to be Auth allowed and store the data in session. @GregSchmidt

Comment: Check the session ID in the cookie on your browser at every step of the process, and see if it's changing or staying the same.

Comment: I think you are correct, I have made an iframe which I have hosted in a 3rd party website. The action which I have given as the source of iframe is calling another 2 methods in AJAX one after another: 1. login to an API and generating token. 2. Uisng that token, I am getting a random video from my library. I am unable to get that token from one action to another using Session. According to you, when I checked, there are 2 session variables from my domain. I guess that's the reason, I am unable to access the session variable. Can you please, suggest me a solution to this problem. @GregSchmidt